# Is there a way to set the width of an element based on how many siblings it has?

Tags: html, css, angular, less

I'm designing a grid layout for my application, and I don't know how many columns it will have. I would love to set the width of the columns dynamically. Instead of dividing by [3] i would like to divide by [n] where [n] is the number of li elements spat out by my foreach in the client side angular code.

I can't use any external library for this project.

```
 li {
                    display:block;
                    float: left;
                    width: calc(~'(100% - 30px)/3');
                    padding-left: 25px;                    
                    text-align: center;
}
```

Is there a way to count the `<li>` elements inside an `<ul>` dynamically?

Comment: https://alistapart.com/article/quantity-queries-for-css

Comment: That doesnt work for me now. I need to count the elements not define what happens if there are more than an exact number or N.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same answer as @Rithwik but JQuery free

```js
function update() {
  return document.querySelectorAll("#counter li").length;
}

document.querySelector(".add").onclick = function() {
  document.querySelector("#counter").innerHTML += "<li>Random</li>";
};
document.querySelector(".count").onclick = function() {
  document.querySelector(".output").innerHTML = update();
};
```

```html
<button class="add">Add item</button>
<button class="count">Get count</button>

<br><br>
<div>Number of li tags : <span class="output"> - </span></div>

<ul id="counter">
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
  <li>D</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Even better! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question on how to dynamically count the number of `<li>` inside a `<ul>`. You can use the javascript `.length` function, a with a bit of JQuery.

```
$("ul li").length; 
// OR Better
$("#id_of_ul li").length;
```

Then you can do manipulations as required as per the number of `<li>`, which can be returned by the function.

```js
function update() {
  return $("#counter li").length;
}


$(".add").on("click", function() {
  $("#counter").append("<li>Random</li>");
});
$(".count").on("click", function() {
  new_count = update();
  $(".output").html(new_count);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="add">Add item</button>
<button class="count">Get count</button>

<br><br>
<div>Number of li tags : <span class="output"> - </span></div>

<ul id="counter">
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
  <li>D</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I can certainly use it! Thank you for being helpful!

Comment: JQuery though :-/ A whole Library for this

Comment: @AndrewBone Well of course anything JQuery does, can be done with simple Javascript, because JQuery is only Javascript. This isnt JQuery imposing by any means. It certainly didnt help that, the requirement was specified hours later. No need to make smiley faces and be so critical about it.

Comment: @Rithwik Sorry didn't want to come across as critical, generally as a rule of thumb unless the OP specifies they have a library it's best to not use one is all 

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why my answer has been downvoted, so I will repost it so that you can see some code.

Flex layout is a very powerful way to make your columns all have the same width; and all behave the same. Basically, it's like a column-based grid (such as bootstrap), but with only a couple of lines of CSS.

Here is the code sample :

```
.parent-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap; // wrap will fit in the parent. nowrap will extend the parent.
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
}

.children {
    flex: 1 1 auto; // All the same width, always
}
```